# Monitoring swap usage of cgroup

Tags: linux, systemd, memory-usage, memory-leak, cgroup

I have a bunch of .NET Core applications running as systemd units. The host is running out of memory and slowly increasing swap usage to 100% so I suspect one or more of the services has a memory leak.

When I run `htop` all the services show under the `dotnet` process so I can't see values for individual services. When I ran `systemd-cgtop` before and after a reboot (going from 100% swap to almost nothing) the memory values for the applications were similar.

How can I find out which systemd unit is using an ever-increasing amount of swap space?

Comment: Although just looking at memory totals should solve your problem, there exists a kernel cmdline option `swapaccount=1` to enable swap accounting per cgroup (typically disabled because its costly)

Answer (score 1):

Get the pid of the dotnet processes sorted by memory

`ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | grep dotnet | grep -v grep | sort -b -k3 -r`

To find the systemd-unit you than ask systemctl

`systemctl status -l <pid>`

Or to just get the process with most memory used:

`systemctl status -l $(ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | grep dotnet | grep -v grep | sort -b -k3 -r | tail -n +2 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')`